# Finding the average of columns from nested lists in a dictionary's value

Tags: python, average

I have a dictionary with 2 keys (dog and cat):

```
d = {'dog': [['4.1', '7.0', 'dog'], ['1.2', '3.4', 'dog']], 'cat': [['1', '8.2', '5.501', 'cat'], ['6.5', '8', '9.1', 'cat']]}
```

I need to find the average of the nested lists of the values for each key. For example, for dog, I need to find the average of 4.1 and 1.2, as well as 7.0 and 3.4.

The problem I'm having is that the nested lists have the numbers as strings. I figured I need an outer while loop to control column number, and then an inner while loop to control row number, however I don't know how to set this up. How do I access the inner list for each key and then access the deeper lists to find the averages?

```
for keys in d:
    for values in d[keys]:
        (2 while loops here)
```

Is this how I would go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming value in dictionary contains list of only two elements (which are again lists):

```
d = {'dog': [['4.1', '7.0', 'dog'], ['1.2', '3.4', 'dog']], 'cat': [['1', '8.2', '5.501', 'cat'], ['6.5', '8', '9.1', 'cat']]}

avg_dict = {}
for key in d:
    avg_list = []
    i = 0
    while (i < len(d[key][0]) - 1):
        avg_list.append((float(d[key][0][i]) + float(d[key][1][i])) /2.0)
        i += 1
    avg_dict[key] = avg_list

print(avg_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def calc_avg(animal):
    vals = [map(float, animal[i][:-1]) for i in range(len(animal))]
    animal_name = animal[0][-1:]
    return map(lambda tup: sum(tup)/len(tup), zip(*vals)) + animal_name    


d = {'dog': [['4.1', '7.0', 'dog'], ['1.2', '3.4', 'dog']], 'cat': [['1', '8.2', '5.501', 'cat'], ['6.5', '8', '9.1', 'cat']]}
print calc_avg(d['cat']) # prints [3.75, 8.1, 7.3004999999999995, 'cat']
```